# WebStorm does not update the project content

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I pasted many files and folders in my project folder. The problem is that WebStorm is still using local history, and I cannot make the IDE refresh the content. Local changes does not affect the real file structure too.

I used:

- Reload all from disk (<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Y</kbd>)
- Reopen the project
- Fix IDE tool, including invalidate all caches
- Removing the `~./cache/JetBrains` folder
- Trying to make a copy of the project and open it in another folder. My IDE does not seem any changes in the system.

VSCode updates everything instantly, but I don't wanna use it. My IDE version is 2022.2.2. There's no `.idea` folder since I just opened it without creating a project.

Comment: *"There's no .idea folder since I just opened it without creating a project."* But the IDE creates that folder when you open a folder like that in the IDE... If I use "Open..." and point to a folder it will make a new project from those files (unless the `.idea` folder is already present; in such a case it will be used).

Comment: Well, there's no .idea folder and I cannot test it with a new project directory, because the local ide file state is different from the real one :(

Comment: It all looks very odd to me. Might be a user mistake even (editing the wrong folder?...) When you use `File | Invalidate Caches...`, choose all options there and restart, the IDE should loose ALL indexes/caches, including Local History. I may only suggest to double check what folders you are deleting: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html

Comment: Looking at the shortcuts and paths you have mentioned -- you seem to be on Linux. How WebStorm was installed -- is it snap or flatpak installation? If so -- try the plain ZIP from JetBrains website or use their ToolboxApp to install the IDE -- it can make a difference. Other than that: use `Help | Contact Support...` to submit a support ticket with WebStorm support team where you can privately provide the needed files (`idea.log` and other requested info)